# A lot of experience or a lot of experiences?

Tags: word-choice, uncountable-nouns, countability, countable-nouns

When I'm in a job review, and I want to say that I'm experienced in something, what is the correct form to say it? (Of course, except of "I am experienced" etc.)

> 1) I have a lot of experience**s**
>
> 2) I have a lot of experience

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Experience can be a countable or uncountable noun.

For your meaning, you would use

> I have a lot of experience. (I have a lot of experience in corporate finance.)

because you are talking about your total experience (in something) as an accumulation of one thing. In that case, experience is grammatically an uncountable (noncount) noun.

See definition 1 [here](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/experience_1), which is marked as *uncountable.*

For a bit more general related information, see [Is experience countable or uncountable?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/34843/is-experience-countable-or-uncountable)